# How to format telephone number in model textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, masking

What is a good way to customize regular textbox for telephone number input ? For example user can insert one of these strings

```
+420123456789
+420 123 456 789
123456789
123 456 789
```

- +420 is a code and there can be different code like +891

and i want it allways shows as

```
+420 123 456 789
```

or

```
123 456 879
```

My Model has this property

```
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

And View is

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="validation-message">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FormVM.Phone)</div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FormVM.Phone, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FormVM.Phone, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
```

Can i use some DataAnnotation attribut or i have to use jQuery and if yes which plugin ?

**Variant 1 - jQuery mask plugin**

```
// Phone Mask
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        onKeyPress: function (cep, e, field, options) {
            var masks = ['+000 000 000 000', '000 000 0000'];
            mask = (cep.replace(/\s/g, '').length > 9) ? masks[0] : masks[1];
            $('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Phone)').mask(mask, options);
        }
    };

    $('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Phone)').mask('000000000000000', options);
});
```

This is two masks I want to enable to user

```
var masks = ['+000 000 000 000', '000 000 0000'];
```

This is default mask at the page start that enable paste both formats if the textbox is empty

```
$('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Phone)').mask('000000000000000', options);
```

This helps me remove spaces and better count phone numbers

```
cep.replace(/\s/g, '').
```

but additional question is, how user can pass '+' symbol ? this '+' symbol is added by mask script but user is allowed to pass only numbers.. I tried some translation option but it did not work, any idea ?

Comment: You can use [link](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) this plugin for masking the textbox. It's pretty good.

Comment: @Qsprec thank you this is what i am looking for but how can i execute "On-the-fly mask change" callback described in the examples ?

Comment: The example is looks clear enough. Just define your masks for your problem like:  var masks = ['+000 000 000 000', '000 000 000']; and choose a condition to change the mask. Take another look at the example again. You will figure out

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that mask method is receiving the option parameter. My ask was where to put the option callback, now its clear, thank you.

Comment: @Qsprec I tried that plugin, but I don't know how to allow the user to put '+' symbol, do you know how to do it ?

Comment: I think you have to change the js file of plugin to make it works. I am not sure but there is a regEx at line:156 of plugin cs file:
 maskChunks.push(mask.charAt(i).replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'));
This can be the thing that blocks '+' symbol. This can mess with something else so be care ;)

Comment: ok I will rather not to try but thank you :)